# How would you simplify this if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm very new to learning JavaScript, so I've used an if/else to categorise some data, but the amount of data is huge.

It's part of a VO2 Max calculator that works out a persons VO2max and then decides if that value is Excellent, down to poor.

The data tables which the values are pulled from might be a way to go? But I don't know how:
[image: Table of data]

How could I simplify this? What can I read to figure it out? Or is it not bad practice to use the below? Thanks.

```
if(vitals.gender === 1) {
            if(vitals.age >= 18 && vitals.age <= 25) {
                if(vo2 > 60) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 52) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 47) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 42) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 37) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 30) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 26 && vitals.age <= 35) {
                 if(vo2 > 56) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 49) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 43) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 40) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 35) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 30) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 36 && vitals.age <= 45) {
                 if(vo2 > 51) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 43) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 39) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 35) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 31) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 26) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 46 && vitals.age <= 55) {
                 if(vo2 > 45) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 39) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 36) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 32) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 29) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 25) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } 
            } else if (vitals.age >= 56 && vitals.age <= 65) {
                 if(vo2 > 41) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 36) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 32) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 30) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 26) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 22) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 65) {
                 if(vo2 > 37) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 33) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 29) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 26) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 22) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 20) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else {
                VO2MaxRating = "Missing";
                document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = 'Either you\re under 18 or missing details';
            }
        } else {
            if(vitals.age >= 18 && vitals.age <= 25) {
                if(vo2 > 56) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 47) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 42) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 38) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 33) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 28) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 26 && vitals.age <= 35) {
                 if(vo2 > 52) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 45) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 39) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 35) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 31) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 26) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 36 && vitals.age <= 45) {
                 if(vo2 > 45) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 38) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 34) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 31) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 27) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 22) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 46 && vitals.age <= 55) {
                 if(vo2 > 40) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 34) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 31) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 28) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 25) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 20) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } 
            } else if (vitals.age >= 56 && vitals.age <= 65) {
                 if(vo2 > 37) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 32) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 28) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 25) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 22) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 18) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else if (vitals.age >= 65) {
                 if(vo2 > 32) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Excellent";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 28) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Good";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 25) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Above Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 22) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 19) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Below Average";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else if (vo2 >= 17) {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                } else {
                    VO2MaxRating = "Very Poor";
                    document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + VO2MaxRating + ")";
                }
            } else {
                VO2MaxRating = 
                document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = 'Either you\re under 18 or missing details';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is considered good practice. You can look into integer bitwise calculations. In places where you have a lot of `if...else` statements, make an array and push `true` or `false` for each category. Then you bitwise mask the array elements and shift them into 1 integer. Then you do bitwise masking and use a `switch...case` (or multiples of them) to determine which best suits you. It may be complicated at first, but it's flexible enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an object of the values you want each option to print out. Based on how your boolean checks are, you can enumerate over the object where the keys are the cutoffs. Then you `break` out of the loop after you get a match.

edit: if you turn the loop into a function, it becomes reusable. Just pass in your `vo2` and the object of values.

```
const VO2MaxRating = {
  52: 'Excellent',
  47: 'Good',
  42: 'Above Average',
  37: 'Average',
  30: 'Below Average',
  0: 'Poor',
}

const setRating = (rate, maxRatingObject) => {
  for (let vo2Rating in maxRatingObject) {
    if (rate >= parseInt(vo2Rating)) {
      return maxRatingObject[vo2Rating]
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("outputVo2").textContent = vo2 + ' ml/kg/min (' + setRating(vo2, VO2MaxRating) + ")";
```